# Send large JSON string from NodeJS to Python

Tags: node.js, python-3.x

I need to send a large JSON file from Node to Python. I can create the child_process with spawn to call the Python file, but I can't work out how to send the data to it. I've tried using pipe, but I'm not understanding the documentation.

**Code:**

```
var dataset = JSON.stringify(doc.data);

// Call the python API
try {
  var py = require('child_process').spawn('python3', ['api.py', analysis, input]);
} catch(error) {
  console.log(error);
}

// Pipe the data to the Python module
py.stdin.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(dataset));
py.stdin.end();
```

**Error:**

```
Uncaught Error: ENAMETOOLONG: name too long, open [file data printed to console here]
```

Comment: You should set up some listeners on events to handle the stream errors and when the stream ends.

Comment: http://lukeramsey.io/child

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2015/08/21/python-nodejs-comm/) is a pretty good guide on what you are trying to do!

Seems like you also should do `py.stdin.write('json data');`